# How to select P tags inside a DIV tag and before the first H3 tag using XPath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<p>Abcd</p>
<p>Abcd</p>
<h3>Head 3.1</h3>
<p>Abcd</p>
<h3>Head 3.2</h3>
</div>
```

I need to Select `<p>` tags inside a `<div>` tag and before the first `<h3>` tag using XPath. How to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did you get? What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[not(preceding-sibling::h3)]` statement in your xpath to only get nodes that do not have `h3` node above them:

```
> response.xpath("//div/p[not(preceding-sibling::h3)]").extract()
< [u'<p>Abcd</p>', u'<p>Abcd</p>']
```